# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in python dictionary

Tags: python

```
def list_gen(a,b,c,d):
    print(a,b,c,d)
    l=[]
    for i in range(a,b):
        for j in range(c,d):
            l.append(d[i,j])
    return l
```

When I pass the arguments to the function list_gen(0,3,0,3) I am getting below error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-ac343943d448> in <module>()
----> 1 list_gen(0,3,0,3)

<ipython-input-49-afc3d3a347a9> in list_gen(a, b, c, d)
      4     for i in range(a,b):
      5         for j in range(c,d):
----> 6             l.append(d[i,j])
      7     return l

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

But this code works without any issues. Can anyone tell what is the error here ?

```
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        print(d[i,j])
```

Comment: `d` is the number `3`. What is `d[i,j]` supposed to mean?

Comment: When you are calling it as list_gen(0,3,0,3), d gets the value of 3. Which is an integer. I believe you wish to do something else.

Comment: By using `d` as a variable in your loop, you have replaced the original `d` which seems to have been a `dict`. Use different variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a global variable `d` containing a dict that you want to access. But you used `d` as the name of a parameter of the function, so that hides the global name. When you use `d[i,j]`, it tries to index the number `3`, which is not possible.

The solution is to use a different variable for the function parameter.

```
def list_gen(a,b,c,e):
    print(a,b,c,e)
    l=[]
    for i in range(a,b):
        for j in range(c,e):
            l.append(d[i,j])
    return l
```

You'll run into problems like this less often if you use more verbose, meaningful variable names than `d`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in range has to be integer and since the `for j in range(c,d):` didn't throw error, it mean d is int and you cannot reference int using d[i,j] in the line `l.append(d[i,j])` . You probably have a variable named d whose scope is active during the print statement.